# Resolve dependency when an assembly is loaded using Assembly.Load(byte[])

Tags: c#

I use Assembly.Load(byte[]) to load an assembly. This loaded assembly internally uses codeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource() to compile code which is failing with error 'The type or namespace name '<ClassName>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'.

AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event is not fired for the references present in the code to compile.

FYI: I am trying to load assembly which uses [FileHelpers.dll](http://www.filehelpers.net/) and it calls on ClassBuilder.ClassFromString function. Assembly load fails with RunTimeCompilationException.

How should I resolve such dependencies?

UPDATE:

Here is code I am using

```
ctor()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomainOnAssemblyResolve;
}

private Assembly CurrentDomainOnAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
    return LoadAssembly(assemblyName);
}

public Assembly GetAssembly(string assemblyFullName)
{
    AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(assemblyFullName);

    Assembly assembly = LoadAssembly(assemblyName) ?? Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
}

private Assembly LoadAssembly(AssemblyName assemblyName)
{
    byte[] assemblyBytes = GetAssemblyBytes(); // Get assembly bytes from external source
    return Assembly.Load(assemblyBytes);
}
```

Thanks

Yash

Comment: Can I see the code?

Comment: Did you list referenced assembly names in CompilerParameters passed to CompileAssemblyFromSource()?

Comment: Yes, the references are fine.
If the assembly is loaded using Assembly.LoadFrom(string assemblyFile), it works fine.
The problem is when Assembly.Load(byte[]) is used.

Comment: @alexm, you are correct. It is an issue with the referenced assemblies. External dll adds references to all assemblies loaded in appDomain whose modules have 'known' FullyQualifiedName. For the assembly loaded using Assembly.Load(byte[]) FullyQualifiedName is '<Unknown>', so it is not added to list of references, thus AssemblyResolve Event is not fired.

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle the `CurrentDomain.ResolveEventHandler` event as below, this event will be triggered whenever a reference is required:

code to load assemblies:

```
private void LoadAssem(){
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
//use File.ReadAllBytes to avoid assembly locking
    Assembly asm2 = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes("AssemblyPath"));
    }
```

Once a reference is needed it will call the below event:

```
 private static string asmBase;
//asmBase contains the folder where all your assemblies found.
        public static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            //This handler is called only when the common language runtime tries to bind to the assembly and fails.

            //Retrieve the list of referenced assemblies in an array of AssemblyName.
            Assembly MyAssembly, objExecutingAssemblies;
            string strTempAssmbPath = "";
            objExecutingAssemblies = args.RequestingAssembly;
            AssemblyName[] arrReferencedAssmbNames = objExecutingAssemblies.GetReferencedAssemblies();

            //Loop through the array of referenced assembly names.
            foreach (AssemblyName strAssmbName in arrReferencedAssmbNames)
            {
                //Check for the assembly names that have raised the "AssemblyResolve" event.
                if (strAssmbName.FullName.Substring(0, strAssmbName.FullName.IndexOf(",")) == args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(",")))
                {
                    //Build the path of the assembly from where it has to be loaded.                
                    strTempAssmbPath = asmBase + "\\" + args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(",")) + ".dll";
                    break;
                }

            }
            //Load the assembly from the specified path.                    
            MyAssembly = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(strTempAssmbPath));

            //Return the loaded assembly.
            return MyAssembly;
        }
```

Comment: I have overridden the event, but for the internal dependencies, this event is not called.

If I use Assembly.LoadFrom(string assemblyFile), then the event is fired, but not when using Assembly.Load(byte[]).

Comment: @yash Am using the above solution to solve the exact same problem that you have... i have all the dll's in one folder `asmBase` and once i load a dll it fires the event for the references.

Comment: Hi @Sufyan, Thanks for the answer.
Mine is a special case. My exact scenario is as follows: I try to load assembly which has reference to FileHelpers.dll (http://www.filehelpers.net), and the assembly uses FileHelpers's ClassBuilder.ClassFromString function. This function compiles code snippet in runtime, and this compilation fails.
For other assemblies, the assembly is properly resolved (ie the event is fired).